# Basic Analysis Help. Open & Closed Sets; Topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I need some help!

First, let me say that I am Mathematics major, as I'm a senior in college finishing up my undergraduate work with the hope of going to graduate school for Mathematics in the future; moreover, I'm independently studying the last few chapters in a Basic Analysis textbook offered by the University of Pittsburgh in Pennsylvania over the summer (summer of 2014).  I was going to wait for the upcoming Fall-2014/2015 semester, and ask a professor for help, but I figured why not give the Math Stack Exchange a try in the meantime.

---

Here's the question (exactly):

$\underline{Proposition}$:  $~~$Let $X$ be a set and $d,$ $d'$ be two metrics on $X$.  Suppose that there exists an $\alpha > 0,$ and $\beta > 0$ $~$such that $\alpha d(x,y) \leq d'(x,y) \leq \beta d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$.  $~~$Show that $U$ is open in $(X,d)$ if, and only if $U$ is open in $(X,d')$. $~~$That is, the topologies of $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ are the same.

---

Here's what I've done so far:

I've tried both directions of the bi-conditional statement, and I figured the trivial part is using the formula that there is an $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta > 0$ $~$such that for all for all $x,y\in X$ yields $\alpha d(x,y) \leq d'(x,y) \leq \beta d(x,y)$.

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction, suppose $U$ is open in $(X,d)$. So, for all $x\in U$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta):=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\delta\}\subset U$. From here, I try defining a $\delta_{_{0}}:=\dfrac{\delta}{\beta}>0$, and take $u\in B(x,\delta_{_{0}})$.  This implies that:

$d'(x,u)\leq\beta d(x,u)<\beta\delta_{_{0}} = \beta\bigg(\dfrac{\delta}{\beta}\bigg) = \delta$; that is, $d'(x,u)<\delta$, and hence $B(x,\delta_{_{0}})\subset B(x,\delta)\subset U$ since $u\in B(x,\delta)$ whenever $u\in B(x,\delta_{_{0}})$. Therefore, $U$ is open in $(X,d')$.

For the $\Leftarrow$ direction, I start to get lost, as I try to do the same thing as above, but, this time, I'll use the fact that $\alpha d(x,y)\leq d'(x,y)$; moreover, I figured to define say a $\delta_{_{1}}:= \alpha\cdot\delta$, and using a similar reasoning as above to show that $U$ is open in $(X,d)$, after assuming $U$ is open in $(X,d')$ of course.

---

What I need assistance on is whether, or not, my proof is correct, if I'm on the right track, if I'm totally incorrect, etc.  My main issue is that $B(x,\delta_{_{0}})\subset B(x,\delta)\subset U$ part for the $\Rightarrow$ implication, for instance.  I'm thinking that I would have to use a minimum between $\delta_{_{0}}$ and $\delta$ in order to ensure the open ball $B(x,\delta_{_{0}})\subset B(x,\delta)$.  I say this because when $\beta\geq1$ the previous inclusion is trivial as $\delta_{_{0}}\leq\delta$, but when $0<\beta<1$, this is where I'm thinking the minimum is needed as I can see that 
$B(x,\delta_{_{0}})\supset B(x,\delta)$ in this case in particular.  Sorry that I made this a bit long, but I figured the more I can get across, the better; also, I've been manipulating the given formula relating $d$ and $d'$ many different ways, and I keep ending up with this same problem:  Simply put, I can't manage to make a smaller open ball within the existential open ball that can be defined with respect to the given assumption when proving one of the two implications from the proposition above.  Any insight, help, hints, different approaches, etc. would be GREATLY appreciated!  PLEASE HELP!

Regarding the *Answer*

Thanks for the help Hayden, for some reason the link won't let me add a comment, but I reworked the problem with your proof and my proof together, and I see what you mean.  I got to step back and look at the topology, and I see now why the question throws in the induced topologies are the same in the last part of the last sentence.  Thank you greatly for your answer!

Comment: But what about the ensuring that an open ball (w.r.t. delta sub 0) will always be a subset, or inside, the "defined" open ball (w.r.t. delta) given by the assumption???  BTW, thank you for your quick answer Hayden, I wasn't even sure if I was on the right track or not.

Comment: See the answer I wrote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Comments turned answer)

You've got the right idea:

We have $B_{d}(x,r/\beta)\subset B_d(x,r)$ because if $d(x,y)<r$, then $d'(x,y)\leq \beta d(x,y)<\beta r$, i.e. $d'(x,y)<r/\beta$.  So given any open set $U$ in the topology induced by the metric $d$, we know that for every point $x\in U$, there is $\delta$ such that $B_d(x,\delta)\subset U$.  So then $B_{d'}(x,\delta/\beta)\subset B_d(x,\delta)\subset U$, from which we find that $U$ is open in the topology induced by the metric $d'$.

Now, for the above direction we only used $d'(x,y)\leq \beta d(x,y)$.  The other direction makes use instead of $\alpha d(x,y)\leq d'(x,y)$.  We can get to the form of the first inequality by dividing both sides by $\alpha$ to get $d(x,y)\leq \frac{1}{\alpha}d'(x,y)$, from which taking the previous proof for the previous direction and replacing $d$ with $d'$, $d'$ with $d$, and $\beta$ with $1/\alpha$, we have a proof of the converse.